# show the page after getting two different service calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i  want to show the page after getting the results of two 
   different service calls.service1 and service2 are two different 
  services

```
don't want to use second service call inside of first service 
subscribe.service1 and service2 are two different services.

  this.service1.getProfile1(id).subscribe((data1) => {
         console.log(data1);
    });
  this.service2.getProfile2(id).subscribe((data2) => {
         console.log(data2);
    });
```

how to i found i got both service calls ?

Comment: may be `forkJoin` both observers

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forkJoin` from rxjs https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

forkJoin(
  this.service1.getProfile1(id), 
  this.service2.getProfile2(id)
).subscribe(([profile1, profile2]) => {
  console.log(profile1, profile2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two observables with a fork join in this way:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

    forkJoin([
      this.service1.getProfile1(id),
      this.service2.getProfile2(id),
    ]).subscribe(r => {
      const data1 = r[0];
      const data2 = r[1];

      console.log(data1);
      console.log(data2);
    });
```

The calls are serialized, and then observable returns with an array of results. The position of the items reflects the order you created the `forkJoin`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in this particular use case you are navigating the user and trying to make a service call with two endpoints. Once you receive a response from those end point you are trying to merge it with fork join and send it to component as a observable

But in your question you are looking for a way to make the http calls even before redirecting to the page. There is a good approach for this use case in angular router.

You can specify what is the http calls which you want to perform even before user taken to a page.

Implement resolve in your service level and define that service under route resolve.

**Example** :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from './api.service';

import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';

import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class APIResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private apiService: APIService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.apiService.getItems(route.params.date);
  }
}
```

**Routes** :

{
  path: 'items/:date',
  component: ItemsComponent,
  resolve: { items: APIResolver }
}